# Going from piecewise to genuine geodesic without decreasing number of intersections?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesics

Let $(M^2,g)$ be a complete, two-dimensional Riemannian manifold be given; also given is $\gamma: [0,\infty) \to M$, an injective geodesic in $M$.

Suppose there are two geodesic segments $\gamma_i : [a_i,b_i] \to M$, $i = 1,2$ with endpoints on $\gamma$ and
\begin{equation}
\gamma_1(b_1) = \gamma_2(a_2).
\end{equation}
Moreover, the points $\gamma_1(a_1),\gamma_1(b_1) = \gamma_2(a_2), \gamma_2(b_2)$ appear in chronological order along $\gamma$.

You may also assume that $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ 'lie on either side of $\gamma$', by which I mean that
\begin{equation}
\langle \gamma_1'(b_1), n \rangle 
\text{ and } \langle \gamma_2'(a_2) , n \rangle
\end{equation}
have the same sign, writing $n \in T_{\gamma_1(b_1)}M$ for the unit normal to $\gamma$.

> The concatenated, piecewise defined geodesic $\gamma_2 \! \cdot \! \gamma_1$ intersects $\gamma$ three times. Is there a genuine geodesic $\Gamma \neq \gamma$ in $M$ that intersects $\gamma$ three or more times?

*Edit.* I've specialized the original question (which was phrased in terms of $N$ geodesic segments), to the special case where $N = 2$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking a bit more?  It seems like it should be easy to produce such $\gamma$ and $\Gamma$ on the cylinder (e.g. with a $\gamma$ a straight line and $\Gamma$ a helix).

Comment: @RBega2 I was thinking to a situation on a cylinder as a counterexample, no?

Comment: @RBega2 I've clarified the question; the manifold $M$ and the geodesic $\gamma$ are meant to be given.

Comment: @PietroMajer Would you like to expand on your comment? On a standard cylinder, $\gamma$ would be a spiral or a straight line; both intersect other spirals infinitely often, no?

Comment: @LeoMoos  For a moment I thought there could be a configuration of  $\gamma_i$ that may skip   the other geodesics so as to get less than $N+1$ intersections, but yes there are too many possibilities

Comment: 'Metric spaces of non-positive curvature' by Bridson and Haefliger on page 4 defines a *geodesic ray* as being distance-minimizing.  This is in fact the standard meaning of the term.  You are apparently using it in a different sense (without the minimisation requirement).  This should be clarified.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thanks for pointing this out; I've removed the reference to geodesic rays.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a counterexample.

Take a cone of unrolled angle strictly between $\frac\pi2$ and $\pi$. Smooth the vertex and take $\gamma$ to be a radial ray far from the vertex. Then you can make a piecewise geodesic which loops around and intersects $\gamma$ as many times as you like, but no genuine geodesic intersects it more than twice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are you sure the example works, though? It seems to fail the first condition, as the points are not in chronological order along $\gamma$, no? Maybe you could make it work by choosing a non-rotationally symmetric smoothing of the vertex.

Comment: In the unrolled sector, there are geodesics from $1$ to $2e^{i\phi}$, $2$ to $3e^{i\phi}$, etc